# Creating .pdb file from existing .mexw64 in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, debugging, mex

I am trying to debug the Matlab NAG function `c06pk` with the MEX file `c06pk.mexw64`. I am following the instructions on the [Matlab help page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html) and using Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C).

The command on the help page

`mex -g yprime.c`

is used to create a `.mexw64` and `.mexw64.pdb` file from a `.c` file. I already have the `.mexw64` file but I don't know how to generate the `.mexw64.pdb` using the `mex -g` command. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Better to write a function in c and debug the NAG function if you have the corresponding .c file for NAG function, if not, I don't think you can debug it.

Comment: I've searched for a `c06pk.c` and `c06pk.f` function, but it doesn't exist

Comment: why would you want to debug it? If you have the manual of the function, you only need to know how to call it.

Comment: I'm currently talking to a Matlab technician. Apparently there is an unknown issue affecting `c06pk` and the engineers are investigating.